# How do I validate the JSON request in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I want to validate the JSON request which I am receiving from the client side.
I have tried using the annotations (`@notnull, @length(min=1,max=8)`, etc., etc.) and it is working fine but the problem is that I am not able to get the fields and messages which will be getting invoked if they are invalid. 
Although, I am getting an error message in my Console.

List of constraint violations:

```
[
  ConstraintViolationImpl
  {
    interpolatedMessage=
    'must be greater than or equal to 900000000',
    propertyPath=phoneNumber,
    rootBeanClass=class
    com.org.infy.prime.RestWithJPA.CarrierFile,
    messageTemplate=
    '{javax.validation.constraints.Min.message}'
  }
  ConstraintViolationImpl
  {
    interpolatedMessage=
    'length must be between 1 and 20',
    propertyPath=accountID,
    rootBeanClass=class
    com.org.infy.prime.RestWithJPA.CarrierFile,
    messageTemplate=
    '{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message}'
  }
]
```

Request if anyone can help me on this or atleast give me an alternative to validate the request in a more efficient manner.

**PS:** I don't want to validate it field by field.

Comment: If you are using @Valid in a controller , you may be able to get the info you want by also including `, BindingResult bindingResult)` in  your method signature.it will contain the bad fields and errors

Comment: Can you show your Entity or model class(coming from client) and controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:
Say this is the request class:

```
public class DummyRequest {

    @NotNull
    private String  code;

    @NotNull
    private String  someField;

    @NotNull
    private String  someOtherField;

    @NotNull
    private Double  length;

    @NotNull
    private Double  breadth;

    @NotNull
    private Double  height;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then, you can write your own generic validate method which will give a "less verbose" constraint violation message, like this:

```
public static <T> List<String> validate (T input) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(input);
    if (violations.size() > 0) {
        for (ConstraintViolation<T> violation : violations) {
            errors.add(violation.getPropertyPath() + " " + violation.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Now, you can validate and check if your request contains any error or not. If yes, you can print it (or send back an invalid request message).

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    DummyRequest request = new DummyRequest();
    request.setCode("Dummy Value");
    List<String> validateMessages = validate(request);
    if (validateMessages.size() > 0 ) {
        for (String validateMessage: validateMessages) {
            System.out.println(validateMessage);
        }
    }
}


Output:
--------
height may not be null
length may not be null
someField may not be null
someOtherField may not be null
breadth may not be null
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this solves your problem.