# Can problemHandler catch Exception of trying to convert empty string to map?

Tags: jackson

I need to create a validator for JSON input and I want to try to defer Exception to be thrown as late as I could. Many Exceptions can be disable by DeserializationFeature like `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL`. For other Exceptions, I am thinking if I could use `DeserializationProblemHandler` to catch all of them so that I have same place to write logic for all fields.

However, the handler is not able to catch all kind of invalid string. Like I want to convert a string to a list. Handler can find "12" is unexpected token but it will not work for string like "" or "foo" or "{".

Is there any way to set some rule like conversion failure using fall back `null` for all fields? Then I can use the returned object to collect error type of all fields.

Comment: Refer this - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators AND this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193178/how-do-i-validate-the-json-request-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thank you Ajay. But this is not in Spring so I cannot direct use those methods, the JSON I need to parse is only controlled in the customized Deserializer and I need to defer Exception thrown when some field is not convertable. The workflow after that is not a problem for me.